# Correct way to make a multi-language site with django

Tags: python, django, multilingual

I am building a website and I am planning to have different languages. I've checked some approaches but they didn't seem to scale very well with many different languages. What is the **correct** and **optimal** way to implement a multi-language site in **Django**?

Comment: That's a very broad question, which is well-covered [by the Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/). Is there something specific that you need help with?

Comment: What approaches did you investigate and how did they fall short? (In what way did they not "scale very well"?)

Comment: i saw someone suggest using cookies but it was not very good for the site SEO, i wanted really to know how to implement the page given if i have 10 copies of the same content in different languages without having multiple pages with the rest of the code for each language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django has a comprehensive i18n library built-in, including text translation, format localization, and timezones. The official documentation for version 1.10 [is available on the Django website](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/).